# How to compare the size of two spheres in scene kit?

Tags: swift, collision-detection, scenekit, renderer

I have 2 spheres in my project at the same location. The firstSphere is smaller and the tempSphere is larger.

EDIT:
**The firstShape will grow larger than the tempShape. When I pause the firstShape I am trying to test like 'if firstShape.scale == tempShape.scale'**

```
//Create Shape
let firstShapeGeo = SCNSphere(radius: shapeRadius)
firstShape.geometry = firstShapeGeo
let shapeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
shapeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.2, green: 0.8, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
firstShapeGeo.materials = [shapeMaterial]
firstShape.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(firstShape)
firstShape.name = "\(shapeNumber)"

// Create Temp Shape
tempShapeRadius = shapeRadius + 1.0

let tempShapeGeo = SCNSphere(radius: tempShapeRadius)
tempShape.geometry = tempShapeGeo
let tempShapeMaterial = SCNMaterial()
tempShapeMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(colorLiteralRed: 0.2, green: 0.8, blue: 0.9, alpha: 0.5)
tempShapeGeo.materials = [tempShapeMaterial]
firstShape.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tempShape)
```

This is how I am growing the firstSphere

```
let grow = SCNAction.scale(to: tempShapeRadius * 2 + 1, duration: 1)
let shrink = SCNAction.scale(to: tempShapeRadius, duration: 1)

let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([grow, shrink])
firstShape.run(SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence))
```

The smaller sphere is growing larger by using `SCNAction.scale` so I do not believe the radius is actually changing. Not sure if this is something you would need to know.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assign the same radius to both spheres. Set the `scale` of your `tempShape` to whatever value makes it the desired amount larger that the initial value of `firstShape`. Now you need only compare `scale`.

Let's suppose you want the `tempShape` sphere to be 3 times the size of the adjustable sphere.

```
let tempScale: CGFloat = 3.0
tempShape.scale = SCNVector3(tempScale, tempScale, tempScale)
// grow from 1 to tempScale, then back to 1
let grow = SCNAction.scaleTo(tempScale, duration: 1)
let shrink = SCNAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 1)
let sequence = SCNAction.sequence([grow, shrink])
firstShape.run(SCNAction.repeatForever(sequence))
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how to compare the scale. I tried comparing scale first but I seemed to keep getting errors.

Comment: It's built into the code snippet. 'grow' is going to scale 'firstShape' until it is the size of 'tempShape' then back down to '1', it's original value.

Comment: I apologize I wasn't clear in the question. The firstShape will grow slightly larger than the tempShape. I am trying to test like 'if firstShape.scale == tempShape.scale' I will update the question

Comment: I think I see. You still need to follow my suggestion of same radius, only the scale changes. That is, limit the size issue to one variable. But then you need to know when the scales become equal. I'm guessing you need to set up an observer to monitor 'firstShape.scale >= tenpShape.scale.  Sorry, I can't help with that part. (Also, be sure to test >= as opposed to ==.)